# Expand wild cards in command before executing it

Tags: bash, command-line, wildcards

Suppose I want to type something like this:

```
rm build/* tmp/*
```

I am about to run it but I want to expand the wildcards before executing so I can verify what is about to happen.  How can I do this?

This is the workflow I am looking for:

```
$ rm build/* tmp/* <press some magic key>
$ rm build/foo build/bar tmp/wiz tmp/buzz
```

(Edit) Another example workflow:

```
$ # Check what is in directory: 
$ ls -0
foo1
foo2
bar
$ # I want to delete foo1 and foo2, but want to do so carefully: 
$ rm f*o <press some magic key>
$ rm foo1 foo2
```

---

I can expand other things like this:

```
cd `hg root` <Ctrl-x>
cd /users/bob/myMercurialRepository
```

(Because I have `Control-x shell-expand-line` in my `~/.inputrc`).

I dug though `man bash` looking at the descriptions of globbing but couldn't find anything interesting.

Comment: It depends on the editing mode of your shell. For example I am using vi-mode and type `<Esc>` and `*` and the wildcards will get expanded.

Comment: One of the things I like about zsh is that this works out of the box, using the <tab> key.  Same with **/* recursive functionality, which I think does not always work with bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the editing mode of your shell. For example I am using vi-mode and type `Esc` and `*` and the wildcards will get expanded.

Comment: Indeed, in the default emacs mode, you can `Ctrl+X` `*`

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
echo rm build/* tmp/*
```

Or, on my version of `bash`, hitting <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> immediately after the wildcard gives me a list of matching files.

To "delete files carefully", I would recommend either using the interaction flag to `rm`, or again prefixing with `echo`

```
echo rm -i f*o
rm -i f*o
```

Admittedly neither will give you the list up front as preferred, though.

Comment: That isn't exactly the behavior I am looking for.  You can enter `rm b*ld` and see that `b*ld` matches `build`.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude true, but not what you asked for in your Question

Comment: updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the behavior is the following (as of O'Reilly's "Learning the bash Shell").

1. <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> will complete up to the longest common prefix if there is more than one match, or complete the file/directory/... name if there's only one match (adding a `/` if it is a directory).
2. <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> behaves similarly, except that it lists
   all completions if there is more than one.
3. <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> echoes what you would obtain with
   <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> and gives back what you typed, without changes.

As an example (I've tried myself), given a directory containing the files

```
aaabbb  aaaccc  aaaddd
```

1. `...$ vi a`<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> would produce `...$ vi aaa•` and leave you in insert mode at the `•`.
2. `...$ vi a`<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> would produce `...$ vi aaabbb aaaccc aaaddd •` and leave you in insert mode at the `•` (as far as I've tried, it adds no `/` if it is a directory).
3. `...$ vi a`<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> would echo `aaabbb  aaaccc  aaaddd` and give you back `...$ vi a`, leaving you in command mode.

It is clear that the trailing `*` in the regex you used is *implied*; you could have written

```
rm build/ tmp/
```

and then pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> **on both** (yes, as far as I can tell and try, <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> expands **all the wildcards only in the space-delimited word the cursor is on**).

But if you put in one wildcard, then the last one is no more implied and you have to supply it explicitly. Indeed, if there is a file named `aaazzzwww`, then writing `a*w`, `aaazzzw`, `a*z*`, or `a*w*` and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> would complete to `aaazzzwww`, but `a*z` wouldn't!

Comment: Those 3 dots before the $ are just hard to follow and make the command look unnecessarily hard.

Comment: @s.ouchene, you can edit the question if you feel like it.